# Sitecore 9.3 Experience Analytics - tracking logged users and users roles

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9, sitecore-analytics, sitecore-xdb

Can anyone provide me with working example how to **show analytics** (Visits, Page views, Page views per visit, etc) **for logged users**? As I understand there is no OOB solution, so I've tried to implement flexible dimensions, but didn't find any good examples and failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you have to identify your logged in contact by calling the `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs()` method, see more details [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/tracking-contacts.html). When the contact logs in you can use their username to identify them upon the successful login.

Note, that the **identification** and **authentication** are separate  unrelated events. Contacts are identified against the xDB and authenticated against the authentication mechanism used by the website.

When the contact identifies, it is saved to xConnect with a known identifier based on the information passed into the`IdentifyAs()` method: *Identifier*, *Source* and
*IdentifierType* will be set to `ContactIdentifierType.Known` (it is set to `ContactIdentifierType.Anonymous` for anonymous contacts). Then you can use `IsKnown` property on the `Sitecore.XConnect.Contact` that returns `true` if a contact has any known identifiers.

If you want to track some custom events for the logged in users to then use them for reporting needs you can add user interactions by calling the `client.AddInteraction()` extension method. I have given an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259446/how-to-track-a-logged-in-user-email-when-a-download-trigger-event-occurs-in-site/67039988#67039988).

If you want to extend the contact with your own custom data then you can create custom contact facets, read more [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/set-contact-facets.html).

In order to implement your custom report with flexible filtering by logged in and not users, of course, you will need to define your custom dimensions and metrics, read more [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/walkthrough--reporting-on-a-new-dimension.html).